# How to derive the complex Fourier series of $s(t) = 1-e^{-2t}$?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, periodic-functions

I have the periodic function $s(t)=1-e^{-2t}$.
I am required to derive the complex Fourier series of $s(t)$.

I have some knowledge of Fourier series but not enough to know if I am doing it correctly. 
If there is other information needed just ask.

Comment: What is the period of $s$?

Comment: 0 < t < T ,

T = -5

is this what you need?

Comment: Did you mean to write $T=5$?

Comment: yeah i did, nice pickup

Comment: OK.  Great.  Now, do you know the integral expression for the coefficients in terms of the function $s(t)$?

Comment: Im trying to find cn with this c_n=1/T ∫_(-infinity)^infinity▒e^(-int)  f(t)  dt

Comment: its hard to read but its the exponential Fourier series frequency domain equation. unsure if this is what you wanted

Comment: Why are the limits $-\pi$ to $\pi$ when the period is $5$?

Comment: i just edited them to be infinity

Comment: The limits are $0$ to $5$.

Comment: ok that makes sense, im trying to follow an example that is different from my question

Comment: I have provided a solution.  Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The coefficients of the complex Fourier Series are given by

$$c_n=\frac{1}{T}\int_0^Ts(t)e^{i2\pi n t/T}dt$$

For $s(t)=1-e^{-2t}$ with a period $T=5$, we have

$$\begin{align}
c_n&=\frac{1}{5}\int_0^5 (1-e^{-2t})\,e^{i2\pi n t/5}dt\\\\
&=\delta_{n,0}+\frac12\,\frac{e^{10}-1}{e^{10}(-5+i\pi n)}
\end{align}$$

where $\delta_{n,m}$ is the Kronecker Delta and equals $1$ for $n=m$ and equals $0$ when $n \ne m$.

Thus, we have

$$s(t)=\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\delta_{n,0}+\frac12\,\frac{e^{10}-1}{e^{10}(-5+i\pi n)}\right)\,e^{i2\pi nt/5}$$

Comment: any chance you could tell me weather the function is odd or even and why?

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure.

Comment: This function is neither even nor odd about $0$.

Comment: any chance you could post the working that you did when you integrated Cn?